# Hierarchical API with a common value

Tags: rust

I have a `Parent` struct, a `Child` struct and a `GrandChild` struct:

```
pub struct Parent {
    pub child_a: ChildA,
    pub child_b: ChildB,
    family_secret: Secret,
}

pub struct ChildA {
    pub grand_child_x: GrandChildX,
    pub grand_child_y: GrandChildY,
}

pub struct GrandChildX {}

// etc.
```

The parent holds a family `Secret` that I want the grandchildren to have access to in their `impl`s.

```
impl GrandChildX {
    pub fn method(&self) {
        // Here I need to use the family secret.
    }
}
```

I am trying to expose a hierarchical API.

```
let parent = Parent::new("our secret");
parent.child_a.grand_child_x.method();
parent.child_b.grand_child_y.method();    // slightly different
```

I've tried a few ways of achieving this, including passing the secret down the family tree.

```
pub struct ChildA {
    family_secret: Secret,
    // ...
}

pub struct ChildB {
    family_secret: Secret,
    // ...
}
```

This has problems moving the value between children (already moved to at `ChildA::new(family_secret: secret)`).

```
impl Parent {
    pub fn new(secret) -> Parent {
        let secret = Secret::new(secret);
        Parent {
            family_secret: secret,
            child_a: ChildA { family_secret: &secret },
            // error move after use ---------^
    }
}
```

I tried passing it down as a reference, but then the value does not live long enough:

```
impl Parent {
    pub fn new(secret) -> Parent {
        let secret = Secret::new(secret);
        Parent {
            child_a: ChildA { family_secret: &secret },
            //                               ^-----<
            // error does not live long enough ----^
    }
}
```

My only success is implementing the `method` as a `trait` of `Parent`, and keeping separate client `struct`s.

```
pub struct ChildAClient<'a> {
    family_secret: &'a Secret,
}

pub trait ChildA {
    fn child_a(&self) -> ChildAClient,        
}

impl ChildA for Parent {
    fn child_a(&self) -> ChildAClient {
        ChildAClient {
            family_secret: &self.family_secret,
        }
    }
}

// Same for ChildB, etc.

pub struct GrandChildXClient<'a> {
    family_secret: &'a Secret,
}

pub trait GrandChildX {
    fn grand_child_x(&self) -> GrandChildXClient,        
}

impl<'a> GrandChildX for ChildAClient<'a> {
    fn grand_child_x(&self) -> GrandChildXClient {
        GrandChildXClient {
            family_secret: self.family_secret,
        }
    }
}
```

This not only feels clunky to author, but it offers a clunky API as well, as I have to import all these traits plus call the trait methods to traverse down the family tree:

```
use my_api::child_a::ChildA;
use my_api::child_a::grand_child_x::GrandChildX;
use my_api::child_b::ChildB;
use my_api::child_b::grand_child_Y::GrandChildY;

let parent = my_api::Parent::new("my secret");

parent.child_a().grand_child_x().method();
parent.child_b().grand_child_y().method();
```

Is there a nice way to pass this secret down the family tree? There is only a single parent, so it makes sense for it to be owned by the parent. How can I borrow it in the descendants?

Comment: I think it is very difficult to come up with a solution to the problem, unless you give more information about the kind of library you are trying to write. For example, would a reference counted `Secret` make sense? If yes, then you no longer have the problem of the secret not living long enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move the ownership of the Secret outside of the Parent and just share a reference to the secret:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Parent<'a> {
    pub child_a: ChildA<'a>,
    family_secret: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct ChildA<'a> {
    pub grand_child_x: GrandChildX<'a>,
    family_secret: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct GrandChildX<'a> {
    family_secret: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Parent<'a> {
    pub fn new(secret: &'a str) -> Parent<'a> {
        Parent {
            family_secret: secret,
            child_a: ChildA::new(secret),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> ChildA<'a> {
    pub fn new(secret: &'a str) -> ChildA<'a> {
        ChildA {
            family_secret: secret,
            grand_child_x: GrandChildX::new(secret),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> GrandChildX<'a> {
    pub fn new(secret: &'a str) -> GrandChildX<'a> {
        GrandChildX{family_secret: secret}
    }
    pub fn method(&self) {
        println!("Secret: {} from grand child", self.family_secret);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let secret = "my secret".to_string();
    let parent = Parent::new(&secret);
    parent.child_a.grand_child_x.method();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4fe78c66314f53d1d215facac9ca722a&version=stable&backtrace=0)

---

Another solution would be to use a [reference counting pointer `Rc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/):

```
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Parent {
    pub child_a: ChildA,
    family_secret: Rc<String>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct ChildA {
    pub grand_child_x: GrandChildX,
    family_secret: Rc<String>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct GrandChildX {
    family_secret: Rc<String>,
}

impl Parent {
    pub fn new(secret: String) -> Parent {
        let secret = Rc::new(secret);
        Parent {
            family_secret: secret.clone(),
            child_a: ChildA::new(secret),
        }
    }
}

impl ChildA {
    pub fn new(secret: Rc<String>) -> ChildA {
        ChildA {
            family_secret: secret.clone(),
            grand_child_x: GrandChildX::new(secret),
        }
    }
}

impl GrandChildX {
    pub fn new(secret: Rc<String>) -> GrandChildX {
        GrandChildX{family_secret: secret}
    }
    pub fn method(&self) {
        println!("Secret: {} from grand child", self.family_secret);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let secret = "my secret".to_string();
    let parent = Parent::new(secret);
    parent.child_a.grand_child_x.method();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9c4a1b8b8acc62237aec203565a18a4c&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: This is suboptimal, because the secret is involved, not just a string, and I'd rather not expose it to the client API.

Comment: @RúnarBerg I added a solution which uses a reference counted pointer. You may want to use [Weak<T>](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html) for the children though.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Here is a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2d263857c8d80e34334c7fa28754a457&version=stable&backtrace=0)/[gist](https://gist.github.com/2d263857c8d80e34334c7fa28754a457) with the full working version